# Getting non-closed contours

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am applying findcontours method in opencv C++. The problem that I am getting contours which seem to be non-closed, a line or curve, but when I check the pixels they are duplicate and sometimes closed. For example:

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
3,3
2,2
1,1
```

I tried to get half of the output pixels but I realized that this problem does not always occur! Sometimes the result is not double. Furthermore, the example I mention is so ideal. Sometimes, the start point is not the same of the end point. For example:

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
3,3
2,2
```

The code is:

```
cv::findContours(canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, cv::Point(0, 0));
```

Thanks in advance :)

Further explanation:
I am applying contouring on an image (canny output) then I want to filter these contours depending on mathematical criteria. In order to be able to use these criteria, I need to know the coordinate (x,y) of each pixel of every contour.
When I view the pixels of a contour, it seems to be like this:

```
  1,1
    2,2
    3,3
    4,4
    3,3
    2,2
    1,1
```

In other words, the line is doubled (two identical lines over each others).
To overcome this problem, I tried to simply remove half of the pixels in order to get some thing like this:

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
```

This method worked well on some contours, but I realized that some contours are doubled in noisy way like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4HBr.png

How could I solve this problem.
Many Thanks

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. What do you mean by: "seem to be non-closed", "pixels are duplicates", "get half of the output pixels", "result is not double", "ideal example"??? And what is the problem exactly? Can you provide data?

Comment: @Trilarion Thanks for your feed back, I am going to provide some information

Comment: @Trilarion I hope it somewhat clear now, many thanks :)

Comment: **why** do you need a hole-free, closed array ? (drawing the contours will at least lead to a closed contour in the image)

Comment: @berak  I need it for Linearity Checking and some other criteria